# How to send error emails with Nlog + Asp.net Core 2.1 + SendGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sendgrid, nlog

I am using nlog with asp.net core 2.1 and send grid(azure) and I am not sure how to send emails through nlog when a error occurs.

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2

I don't really see anything in the above doc on how to send emails via nlog, I am not sure if the same setup that was used in non .net core could be used?

I am using the api version for sendGrid and I know they do have smtp option but not sure if you can use both.

Comment: "I don't really see anything in the above doc". What are you looking for? I see a lot of text ;)

Comment: Your question is very broad. Could you narrow it down?